# Can one use the Wronskian to find both solutions of a 2nd order homogenous DE?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have a 2nd order homogenous differential equation of the form $y'' + p(x)y' + q(x)y=0$. Using Abel's theorem, I was able to find the Wronskian (it's non-zero), but I am not sure where to go from here.

Most lecture notes online mention using the Wronskian to find the second solution given the first, but they don't seem to mention whether or not it is possible to find both given the Wronskian. Is it possible to find both solutions to my differential equation given the Wronskian?

Comment: If it matters, I do not know the exact form of $p(x)$, but I know that $p$ and $q$ are related (e.g. I know $q[p(x)]$). Finding a solution in terms of $y[x,p(x)]$ would be good enough.

Comment: I think that Abel's theorem or the use of the Wronskian is particularly useful when at least one of the solutions to the homogenous equation is known already. Otherwise, I don't see how one could determine your desired form of solution $y(x;p)$ just by knowing $W(y_1,y_2)$. If you may, can you provide more details of your ODE?

Comment: The full equation is $\ddot{X}+\left(3\frac{\dot{a}}{a}-\frac{\dot{R}}{R} \right) \dot{X}-4\frac{\kappa^2}{R}X=0$ where $R\equiv 6\left[ \frac{\ddot{a}}{a}+\left(\frac{\dot{a}}{a} \right)\right]$ (where overdot is a derivative). From Abel's Theorem, the Wronskian is $W=C\frac{R}{a^3}$. In looking, I did find [this](http://www.stumblingrobot.com/2016/01/31/use-the-wronskian-to-find-all-solutions-of-a-given-second-order-differential-equation/) blog post claiming it can be done.